# Programmatically compiling .java files, error

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, javac

When run this code to compile a .java file in this directory:

```
String title = txtName.getText();
        String name = title + ".Java";
        String src = Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getParent().toString() + "/saves/" + world.getWorldInfo().getWorldName().toString() + "/TechRev/Compiler/";
        compile(src + name);
```

With this method:

```
public void compile(String file) {
    String fileToCompile = file;
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
    if (compilationResult == 0) {
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
}
```

I get this error in the console of Eclipse Juno(Java 6):

```
2013-10-02 20:47:47 [INFO] [STDERR] javac: invalid flag: /Users/marko5049/Desktop/Modding/forge/mcp/jars/saves/TechRev/TechRev/Compiler/TechRev.Java
2013-10-02 20:47:47 [INFO] [STDERR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
2013-10-02 20:47:47 [INFO] [STDERR] use -help for a list of possible options
2013-10-02 20:47:47 [INFO] [STDOUT] Compilation Failed
```

Please could someone explain to me why this is happening and show me how to fix this? thanks!

-Regards
Mark

Answer (score 6):

Your filename ends with `.Java` - it should be `.java`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't expect it to be a source file, and tries to process it as a flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

**.java** not  **.Java**

```
String name = title + ".Java";
```

change this to

```
`String name = title + ".java"`;
```